# How to make it so that "Show more" & "Show less" buttons only work for the text in their own div and not for all texts using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently, I display the first 240 characters of each review at all times and if `showMore` is true, I display the rest of the characters. The "Show more" & "Show less" buttons change the value of `showMore` to true and false respectively. Sadly this implementation shows and hides the text of all reviews which is a problem.

Is my implementation of the "Show more" & "Show less" too simplistic right now? Is there any quick fix to my problem or do I have to rewrite stuff?

```
<template>
    <div v-for='review in reviews'>
        <div>
            <p>{{ review.text.slice(0,240) }}
                <span v-show='!showMore' v-if='review.text.length > 240'>...</span>
                <span v-show='showMore' class='extra-text'>{{ review.text.slice(240) }}</span>
            </p>
            <p v-show='!showMore' @click='showMore = true'>Show more</p>
            <p v-show='showMore' @click='showMore = false'>Show less</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            reviews: null,
            showMore: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```